# How to init an object in a JUnit test?

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to do a JUnit test to test a Controller.

My Controller consists of:

```
    @Autowired
    private OrderManager orderManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getOrderList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> getOrderTables(OrderSearchDto orderSearchDto) {
         ...
         orderHdrTables = orderManager.findAllOrders(orderSearchDto);
         ...
    }
```

and my test is:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FilterActivityTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private OrderHdrController orderHdrController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(orderHdrController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testActivityFilter() throws Exception {

        OrderSearchDto orderSearchDto = new OrderSearchDto();
        OrderSearchPanelDto orderSearchPanelDto = new OrderSearchPanelDto();
        List <String> activityTypes = Arrays.asList("DELIVERY","START_UPLOAD");
        orderSearchPanelDto.setActivityTypes(activityTypes);
        orderSearchDto.setOrderSearchPanelDto(orderSearchPanelDto);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/orders/getOrderList")     
        .content(asJsonString(orderSearchDto))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.data[0].tripNo", is("SG1606LLR08469")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.data[1].tripNo", is("SG1606LLR08470")));;
    }

    private static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
        try {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final String jsonContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
            return jsonContent;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }  
}
```

But during debug of the test, I am getting orderManager is null in my Controller. What can I do to initialise it?

Comment: do you want to perform just controller test or integration test ?

Comment: integration test. How do I go about it?

Comment: see this https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: Hi Deadpool Thanks for the link. It mentions @MockBean which is in Spring Boot. But I am using Spring. What can I do?

Comment: @Mock
private OrderManager orderManager;

Comment: Thanks @AtulKumbhar. But when I run it, my orderSearchPanelDto object is null in the controller during debug. Please help.

Comment: Can you please post whole method in controller, we should be able to see how you retrieve orderSearchPanelDto . may be you need more mocking

Comment: I was in debug mode and I hover my mouse over the orderSearchDto object in the param. It shows orderSearchPanelDto is null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the mocks

Update your `@BeforeEach` method like this:

```
@Mock
private OrderManager orderManager;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(orderHdrController).build();
}
```

Also, you may not need `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Comment: The `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` already does `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`

Comment: Thanks Sunil. But orderSearchPanelDto object in orderSearchDto object is still null. Please help.

Comment: Do you have a non-empty constructor for your controller by any chance? And what is your JUnit version?

Comment: No, I don't have a non-empty constructor for my controller. My JUnit is 4.12

Comment: If not done already, can you put your test under same package as your controller and try?

Comment: I think @AtulKumbhar was right. However, your next problem seems different from your question. `null` `orderSearchPanelDto`. This tells me your `OrderSearchDto` either had non-empty constructor OR did not have setter for `orderSearchPanelDto`

Comment: @SunilChakravarthy please note in the test "new OrderSearchDto()" and "orderSearchDto.setOrderSearchPanelDto" is present

Comment: @AlanTT kindly add `OrderSearchPanelDto` class in your question

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your test a bit. Please try this.

```
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        FilterActivityTest.Config.class,
        OrderHdrController.class,
})
public class FilterActivityTest {

@Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        OrderManager orderManager() {
            return mock(OrderManager.class);
        }
    }

@Autowired
private OrderHdrController orderHdrController;

@Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(orderHdrController).build();
        //remember to mock orderManager.findAllOrders here
    }


}
```